# convert criteria to detached criteria for self join

Tags: java, hibernate, self-join, detachedcriteria

I would like to know if i can convert this criteria into a detached criteria. I am not understanding detached criteria correctly. can some one help.

```
Criteria crit = sessionC.createCriteria(OP_DOCTOR_VISIT.class, "OPDV1");
crit.createAlias("OPDV1.OP_VISIT", "OPDV2", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN, Restrictions.and(Restrictions.eq("OPDV2.FORM", "NEW"), Restrictions.ge("OPDV2.USER_DATETIME", fromdate), Restrictions.le("OPDV2.USER_DATETIME", todate)));
    crit.add(Restrictions.ge("OPDV1.USER_DATETIME", fromdate));
    crit.add(Restrictions.le("OPDV1.USER_DATETIME", todate));
    ProjectionList p1 = Projections.projectionList();
    p1.add(Projections.alias(Projections.count("OPDV1.OP_VISIT_ID"), "TOTAL"));
    p1.add(Projections.count("OPDV2.FORM"));
    p1.add(Projections.alias(Projections.sqlGroupProjection("date(this_.USER_DATETIME) as createdDate", "createdDate", new String[]{"createdDate"}, new Type[]{StandardBasicTypes.DATE}), "DAT"));
    crit.setProjection(p1);
```

Is it possible to rewrite the above so that I could avoid using "@OneToMany" in my POJO given below.

POJO

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "OP_DOCTOR_VISIT")
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE OP_DOCTOR_VISIT SET DELETED = 'DELETED' WHERE OP_VISIT_ID = ? and VERSION_UPDATES = ?")
@Where(clause = "DELETED <> 'DELETED'")
public class OP_DOCTOR_VISIT implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "OP_VISIT_ID")
private Long OP_VISIT_ID;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "OP_VISIT_ID", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
private List<OP_DOCTOR_VISIT> OP_VISIT;

    public Long getOP_VISIT_ID() {
        return OP_VISIT_ID;
    }

    public void setOP_VISIT_ID(Long OP_VISIT_ID) {
        this.OP_VISIT_ID = OP_VISIT_ID;
    }

    public List<OP_DOCTOR_VISIT> getOP_VISIT() {
        return OP_VISIT;
    }

    public void setOP_VISIT(List<OP_DOCTOR_VISIT> OP_VISIT) {
        this.OP_VISIT = OP_VISIT;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only the first line where you create your criteria object.

1. `DetachedCriteria` allows you to create a query without session. So you do not require session while builiding your query. `DetachedCriteria` is  same as a Criteria except you can create your queries without session.

   DetachedCriteria detachedCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(OP_DOCTOR_VISIT.class);
2. Finally when you have a session object is available you may execute your query

   `criteria .getExecutableCriteria(session).

Answer (score 0):

***DetachedCriteria crit = DetachedCriteria.forClass(OP_DOCTOR_VISIT.class, "OPDV1");***

The detached criteria allows you to create the query **without Session**. Then you can execute the search in an arbitrary session.

In fact you should think carefully when use detached criterias using another, or a new, session **(no cache, and creation of the session)**.

They are most useful for make some join conditions, subselects, and to query outside the current session.
Another common use is for code reuse.

**If you are using Spring and choose to use HibernateTemplate, it doesn't provide createCriteria() method.
You will find only **DetachedCriteria.**

Comment: can u please explain the second sentence. "In fact you should think carefully when use detached criterias using another, or a new, session (no cache, and creation of the session)."

Comment: DetachedCriteria not using any session.So don't use/link it with session.i.e. no cache is available.It is always early loading.